# Paypal API cache

Tags: api, paypal

I've been looking for a way to get payments out of Paypal with the API.
Currently I'm doing this with 'v1/reporting/transactions'.
The thing here is that there is a 'last_refreshed_datetime', which means it can take a few hours before new transactions load in.

Does someone have an idea to force a transactions update or another way to get them?

- Quartz

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use a server-side integration to capture all orders, then you have an immediate notification of every single new transaction.

See 'Create Order' and 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls).

You can use those to create two server routes that only return JSON, and pair them with this approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

If for some reason you're not able to use that best of integration methods, you could subscribe to webhooks or use IPN for an asynchronous notification of new transactions.

Comment: With both of these ways you are not allowed to get the description from the transaction, which is what I need.

Comment: If you are capturing an order, you should know what is in the order. You can get its details if you really need to, and you will receive the transaction ID. Not sure what else you are expecting.